# Image preloading working in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, random, preload

My goal is to preload images that are in an array and then display a random image instantly on the click of a button. On the next click another random image from the array should appear. Here is the code:

```
let randomImage = new Array(24);

function preload() {
    for (let x = 1; x < randomImage.length; x++) {
    randomImage[x] = "img/img" + x + ".jpg";
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < randomImage.length; ++i) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = randomImage[i];
    }
}

function randomImg() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);
    if (random === 0) {
    return randomImage[1];
    }

document.getElementById("img_placeholder").src = randomImage[random];

}
```

What this is supposed to do is first preload the array with images (the preload() function).

Then the randomImg() function is called everytime a button is pressed. This works fine for safari, but in chrome it first preloads all images correctly but then when I click the button to go to the next random image it sends another get request to load the image again, oposed to in safari where it just takes the loaded image.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the view when the page is loaded, the images also load:
[image]

But when the button to change to a random picture is pressed the images are still loaded again:
[image]

This is only with chrome, it works fine with firefox and safari.

Comment: Where are you calling `preload()`? There are also lots of issues with your code. For example `random` seem to be defined in `randomImg()` but then you try to use it where it's out of scope with `randomImage[random]`

Comment: I am calling preload() in the html file -> <body onload="preload()"...
random isn't used out of scope it is still in the function randomImg()